# Group by on two tables and then append results and remove duplicates

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables with multiple columns in each of them. As can be seen below the column headers are not the same name. 
I would like to do a GROUP BY on the first and second column of EACH table and then in the output, the results should be appended and not have any duplicates. Also the results only needs the first two columns as the output.

Tablename = STAT

```
Region   Brand  M08 
-----------------
P1       A      xx     
P1       A      yy    
P2       B      zz     
P2       C      yy      
P3       A      uu     
P3       B      ii    
P3       C      oo
```

TABLE NAME = MI

```
RegDes   P4Brand  M08 
-----------------   
P2       B        er    
P2       C        tr     
P3       A        ty     
P3       B        ew    
P4       C        yu  
P4       A        tr     
P4       B        ty     
P5       C        yu
```

TABLE NAME = EXPECTED_OUTPUT

```
Region   Brand   
-----------------  
P1       A              
P2       B          
P2       C         
P3       A          
P3       B         
P4       C     
P4       A         
P4       B        
P5       C
```

I need some help writing the SQL script for this. I have already created the schema for the 3 tables .
The final output will be inserted into the Table: EXPECTED_OUTPUT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `UNION ALL` to combine both tables in 1 unique. Then, wrap a `SELECT *` around that query and apply a `GROUP BY`

Or, instead of using a `GROUP BY` I would do the same as above, but using a `SELECT DISTINCT *`

Or, as stated @Usagi Miyamoto in comments, using simple a `UNION` (without `ALL`)

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
CREATE TABLE stat (
  `Region` VARCHAR(2),
  `Brand` VARCHAR(1),
  `M08` VARCHAR(2)
);

INSERT INTO stat
  (`Region`, `Brand`, `M08`)
VALUES
  ('P1', 'A', 'xx'),
  ('P1', 'A', 'yy'),
  ('P2', 'B', 'zz'),
  ('P2', 'C', 'yy'),
  ('P3', 'A', 'uu'),
  ('P3', 'B', 'ii'),
  ('P3', 'C', 'oo');



CREATE TABLE mi (
  `RegDes` VARCHAR(2),
  `P4Brand` VARCHAR(1),
  `M08` VARCHAR(2)
);

INSERT INTO mi
  (`RegDes`, `P4Brand`, `M08`)
VALUES
  ('P2', 'B', 'er'),
  ('P2', 'C', 'tr'),
  ('P3', 'A', 'ty'),
  ('P3', 'B', 'ew'),
  ('P4', 'C', 'yu'),
  ('P4', 'A', 'tr'),
  ('P4', 'B', 'ty'),
  ('P5', 'C', 'yu');
```

---

**Query #1 GROUP BY**

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
    SELECT s.Region AS Region, s.Brand AS Brand
    FROM stat s
    UNION ALL
    SELECT m.RegDes AS Region, m.P4Brand AS Brand
    FROM mi m
) AS EXPECTED_OUTPUT
GROUP BY Region, Brand;
```

**Output**

```
| Region | Brand |
| ------ | ----- |
| P1     | A     |
| P2     | B     |
| P2     | C     |
| P3     | A     |
| P3     | B     |
| P3     | C     |
| P4     | A     |
| P4     | B     |
| P4     | C     |
| P5     | C     |
```

---

**Query #2 DISTINCT**

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM 
(
    SELECT s.Region AS Region, s.Brand AS Brand
    FROM stat s
    UNION ALL
    SELECT m.RegDes AS Region, m.P4Brand AS Brand
    FROM mi m
) AS EXPECTED_OUTPUT;
```

**Output**

```
| Region | Brand |
| ------ | ----- |
| P1     | A     |
| P2     | B     |
| P2     | C     |
| P3     | A     |
| P3     | B     |
| P3     | C     |
| P4     | C     |
| P4     | A     |
| P4     | B     |
| P5     | C     |
```

---

**Query #3 UNION**

```
SELECT s.Region AS Region, s.Brand AS Brand
FROM stat s
UNION
SELECT m.RegDes AS Region, m.P4Brand AS Brand
FROM mi m;
```

**Output**

```
| Region | Brand |
| ------ | ----- |
| P1     | A     |
| P2     | B     |
| P2     | C     |
| P3     | A     |
| P3     | B     |
| P3     | C     |
| P4     | C     |
| P4     | A     |
| P4     | B     |
| P5     | C     |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rEt6ydt3AvffpWLMfHAs4p/2)

---

To insert that result in a table, you can use the `INSERT INTO SELECT` statement :

**Group By query**

```
INSERT INTO EXPECTED_OUTPUT
SELECT * FROM 
(
    SELECT s.Region AS Region, s.Brand AS Brand
    FROM stat s
    UNION ALL
    SELECT m.RegDes AS Region, m.P4Brand AS Brand
    FROM mi m
) AS EXPECTED_OUTPUTDATAS
GROUP BY Region, Brand;
```

**DISTINCT query**

```
INSERT INTO EXPECTED_OUTPUT
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM 
(
    SELECT s.Region AS Region, s.Brand AS Brand
    FROM stat s
    UNION ALL
    SELECT m.RegDes AS Region, m.P4Brand AS Brand
    FROM mi m
) AS EXPECTED_OUTPUTDATAS;
```

**UNION query**

```
INSERT INTO EXPECTED_OUTPUT
SELECT s.Region AS Region, s.Brand AS Brand
FROM stat s
UNION
SELECT m.RegDes AS Region, m.P4Brand AS Brand
FROM mi m;
```

Comment: thank you. And if I wanted to insert this result into my Expected_Output table how do I insert this ?

Comment: Also `SELECT ... AS` does not insert data into an existing table, it creates a new one...

Comment: @UsagiMiyamoto oh yes, true, I never used `UNION` without `ALL`

Comment: Thank you both. So do I use Union or Union All for the final expected output ?